# Как поставить выполнение всего скрипта на паузу?

Tags: python, ос, multiprocessing, pyautogui

У меня есть скрипт который в с некоторой периодичностью двигает мышкой и обновляет страницу (нажимает ф5). Я хочу чтобы была возможность поставить скрипт на паузу (чтобы таймер который отсчитывает время до передвижения мышки и обновления страницы замораживался по нажатию клавиши или сочетания клавиш), а также чтобы осталась возможность быстрого закрытия нажатием ctrl + shift + alt + s.

```
import random
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import os
import signal
import keyboard
import multiprocessing as mp


# процесс убийства приложения
def hook(pid):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl + shift + alt + s'):
            os.kill(pid,signal.SIGTERM)
            os._exit(1)

def pause():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + shift + alt + p"):
            print('Скрипт приостановлен, нажмите p для продолжения')
            keyboard.wait('p')
            print("Скрипт продолжается...")
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    pid = os.getpid()
    mp.Process(target=hook,args=[pid]).start()

    # случайные движения мышкой + перезагрузка страницы
    while True:
        mp.Process(target=pause).start()
        a, b, c = random.randint(500,1000), random.randint(300,600), random.randint(1, 5)

        try:
            sleep(10)
            pg.moveTo(a, b, c)
            sleep(40)
            pg.press('f5')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

Я пытался сделать отдельную функцию `pause`, разными методами (ожидание инпута, `keyboard.wait` и др), но скрипт либо ломался, либо не останавливался.

Comment: А почему пауза в другом процессе?

Comment: Потому что я не очень знаком с `multiprocessing` и переписывал код несколько раз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно исполнить через `threading`. К примеру так:

```
import random
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import os
import keyboard
import threading

flag = True # Флаг состояния потока moveTo_pressF5_thread

# Функция для убийства приложения
def hook_exit():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl + shift + alt + s'):
            os._exit(1)

# Функция для случайных движений мышкой и перезагрузки страницы
def moveTo_pressF5():
    global flag
    while flag:
        a, b, c = random.randint(500,1000), random.randint(300,600), random.randint(1, 5)
        sleep(10)
        pg.moveTo(a, b, c)
        sleep(40)
        pg.press('f5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создаем поток для выхода по нажатию сочетания клавишь
    hook_exit_thread = threading.Thread(target=hook_exit)
    hook_exit_thread.start() # Запускаем поток
    
    # Создаем поток для движении мыши и обновления страницы
    moveTo_pressF5_thread = threading.Thread(target=moveTo_pressF5)
    moveTo_pressF5_thread.start() # Запускаем поток

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + shift + alt + p"):
            flag = False
            print('Скрипт приостановлен, нажмите p для продолжения')
            
            keyboard.wait('p')
            flag = True
            
            moveTo_pressF5_thread = threading.Thread(target=moveTo_pressF5)
            moveTo_pressF5_thread.start()
            
            print("Скрипт продолжается...")
```

Дополнение:

Сам `thread` можно остановить только по флагу(завершению итерации цикла), но если нужно именно **"убить"**, то воспользуйтесь `multiprocessing`, у него есть метод `.terminate()`.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def my_function():
    while True:
        print("Running...")
        time.sleep(1)

# Создаем процесс
my_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)

# Запускаем процесс
my_process.start()

# Ждем 5 секунд
time.sleep(5)

# Принудительно завершаем процесс
my_process.terminate()
# Ждем 5 секунд для наглядности
time.sleep(5)
print("!!!")
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже попробовал через `threading`, но код был кривой, однако остаётся проблема которую я так и не понял как решить - приходится ждать завершения цикла. Есть ли возможность сразу приостановить на том же месте где и был остановлен поток, ну или хотя бы полностью убить его, а потом после нажатия клавиши снятия с паузы запустить его заново?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.